# Real analysis proof regarding continuity and intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

Let : [, ] →  be a continuous function on [, ] such that for each  ∈ [, ] there is  ∈ [, ] such that | − | ≤ 1/2|()| and |()| ≤ 1/2|()|. Prove that there is a point <sub>0</sub> ∈ [, ] such that (<sub>0</sub>) = 0.

I tried using the intermediate value theorem to prove this but didn't get anywhere. Can someone point out how to carry out the proof?

Comment: I think the intention was to have you construct a sequence $x_n$ where $x_0$ is arbitrary and $x_{n+1}$ is the $y$ belonging to $x_n$, and having you prove that this sequence converges and that its limit has the desired property. But indeed the first condition is superfluous because you can choose a convergent subsequence due to compactness of $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it only needs the condition *for each  ∈ [, ] there is  ∈ [, ] such that |()| ≤ 1/2|()|.*

Assume by contradiction that $\min_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|>0$. We know that there is a $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $|f(x_0)|=\min_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$ by the continuity of $|f|$. Then by the condition, we know that there is $y_0\in[a,b]$ such that $|f(y_0)|\leq\frac{1}{2}|f(x_0)|$, which implies $|f(x_0)|\leq|f(y_0)|\leq\frac{1}{2}|f(x_0)|<|f(x_0)|$ since $|f(x_0)|>0$, contradiction.

Comment: This was indeed what was expected. Thank you very much.